# Time Complexity of Nested Loops with Conditional

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

The problem I need help with is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n*n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n*n; j++)
        if (i == j)
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                sum++;
```

I understand how the `i` and `j` loops are O(n^4). But, starting with the if statement, I don't know what Big O of remaining code fragment is. If I copied the answer down correctly in class, O(n^4) is the running time for the entire code snippet. So, the running time starting at the if seems negligible. THOUGH, I'd still like to understand what it is and why for I took the answer to be O(n^5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The overall complexity of your code is actually `O(n^4)`, not `O(n^5)`.  The condition `i == j` will happen once for each value in the range of the two outer loops in `i` and `j`.  As there are `n^2` possible values in each of these loops, `i == j` will happen `n^2` times.  For each time this happens, there is a third loop in `k` which will iterate `n` times.  So, each time that `i == j` occurs, there will be an `O(n)` penalty.  Overall, this manifests as an `O(n^3)` event, which dwarfs the `O(n^4)` performance of the two outer loops.

**Therefore**, the behavior of your code snippet is still `O(n^4)`, despite the `i == j` condition.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. Sounds like you know this stuff pretty well. From conscious practice?

Answer (score 0):

O(n^4) is the correct answer. First two loops has O(n^4) time complexity. For part of code starting from 'if' statement, complexity is O(n^3), as 'i' and 'j' are equal exactly n*n times and there is another for loop which increases the time complexity to O(n^3).
Hence, O(n^4) + O(n^3) = O(n^4)

Comment: Wait. Why add O(n^4) and O(n^3)? Aren't you supposed to multiply the two cause of the nesting?

Comment: No. Think it like this. Outer for loops will run O(n^4) times and out of these O(n^4) times, inner for loop will run  only O(n^2) times. Hence, it will be an addition.

Comment: Oh, snap. Interesting. Thanks for further explaining.